# Loop for including a list instead of an individual in ggenealogy package in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to trace back a pedigree and I have a package to do it for specific individuals but instead, I need to use a list of 2000 animals. What I need is all the ancestors of each individual 5 generations back .

Here it is an example:

```
library(ggenealogy)
data(sbGeneal)
getAncestors("5601T", sbGeneal, 5)
```

I need to use a list of individuals instead of writing one by one the name of the animals.

Would it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
library(ggenealogy)
data(sbGeneal)
lst <- sapply(sbGeneal[,1], function(x) getAncestors(x, sbGeneal, 5))
```

It gets all results done and store them to a list `lst`. This is just a rough idea. You may need to adjust the code. 
To retrieve those values:

```
lst$`5601T` 
lst$Adams
```

would be the same as

```
getAncestors("5601T", sbGeneal, 5)
getAncestors("Adam", sbGeneal, 5)
```

Comment: I'm glad it helps.